# VueJs build error - Vuex-orm / plugin-axios

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, build, vuejs2

I have a VueJs app based on Webpack 2.

I installed all modules successfully, but when I try to build the app, I receive this error:

```
ERROR in ./~/@vuex-orm/plugin-axios/dist/vuex-orm-axios.esm-browser.js
Module parse failed: node_modules/@vuex-orm/plugin-axios/dist/vuex-orm-axios.esm-browser.js Unexpected token (38:57)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|         }
|         const options = this.getPersistOptions();
|         this.entities = await this.model[method]({ data, ...options });
|         this.isSaved = true;
|     }
 @ ./src/store/store.js 9:0-50
 @ ./src/main.js
```

Any idea how can I fix it?

I tried to downgrade the @vuex-orm/plugin-axios to version  0.9.2 but I receive the same error. Right now I'm using the latest version of @vuex-orm/plugin-axios, which is 0.9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the following error appears:

> ERROR in ./~/@vuex-orm/plugin-axios/dist/vuex-orm-axios.esm-browser.js
> Module parse failed:
> /vue-src/node_modules/@vuex-orm/plugin-axios/dist/vuex-orm-axios.esm-browser.js
> Unexpected token (38:57)

downgrade the @vuex-orm/plugin-axios version using:

```
sudo npm install @vuex-orm/plugin-axios@0.9.1 --save
```

For me it didn't worked to install version 0.9.2, but it worked well with version 0.9.1